# Can i access camera from gStreamer to stream information in RTSP (gst-rtsp-server)

Tags: android, camera, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm actually working on a prototype to stream camera video using gst-rtsp-server in GStreamer. I'm trying to figure out the best way to access the camera video to send information to the RTSP Server. I want something where i can get the best performance in term of Live Streaming.

Thanks.